# Concatenar valores numericos en un array usando un guion

Tags: php

```
 <?php

$tipo = $_POST["radatenua"];

if ($tipo > 0) {

    if ($tipo == 40) {

        $atenuantes = $_POST["atenuantes"];
        foreach ($atenuantes as $at):
            $atenuante1 .= $at . "-";
        endforeach;

    }

    elseif ($tipo == 41) {
        $agravantes = $_POST["agravantes"];
        foreach ($agravantes as $ag):
            $agravante1 .= $at;
        endforeach;
    }

}
?>
```

Poseo este código donde dependiendo de un `radiobutton` te hace un determinado guardado en la base de datos, es un sistema que no es mio, por lo tanto ahí un error en la base de datos, y entonces me piden guardar los distintos **atenuantes** o **agravantes** en un determinado campo, es decir, que debería guardar algo asi: 1-2, 7-8, 1-1. porque luego un código específico corta ese `array`.

como podría modificar mi código para que los guarde así?

Actualmente los guarda así: 56 78 1011

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion *implode()* de PHP.

*implode()*, realiza una separacion del array y los "pega" indicando con que caracter los deseas unir, en este caso con un guion.

```
<?php

$arreglo = array(56, 78, 1001);

print implode("-", $arreglo);

?>
```

> Resultado

```
php prueba.php 
56-78-1001
```

Mas informacion: *[implode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php)*

Como en tu caso `$atenuantes` es el arreglo, podrias hacer esto:

```
$agravante1 = implode("-", $atenuantes);
```

Comment: uso $agravante1.=implode("-", $ag) o $agravante1 =implode("-", $ag)

Asi me guarda vacio

Comment: @VictorA. Ya la edite explicando tu pregunta

Comment: gracias, probare directo al arreglo

Comment: @VictorA. De acuerdo, espero tu resultado :)

Comment: una duda aparte jejeje, como vez tengo un if =0, con javascript hago el cambio entre radiobutton, para mostrar los checkbox, en el caso de que usen ninguno, no habra checkbox, por lo tanto la varaible quedara vacia, eso generaria problemas?, no importa si quedan atenuantes y agravantes vacios

Comment: **Me guardo vacio**

Comment: if($tipo>0){
 if($tipo==40) {
 
$atenuantes=$_POST["atenuantes"];
foreach ($atenuantes as $at):
$atenuante1 = implode("-", $agravantes);
endforeach;

 }elseif($tipo==41){
$agravantes=$_POST["agravantes"];
foreach ($agravantes as $ag):
$agravante1 = implode("-", $agravantes);
endforeach;
}

Comment: @VictorA. Te recomendaria que formularas otra pregunta en donde expusieras el codigo javascript y lo que necesitas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53399/discussion-between-ivan-botero-and-victor-a).